# c# List.Add() unable to add correct values

Tags: c#, winforms

Program suppose to draw shapes on panel1.
This is code for my main form:

```
namespace DrawShapes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Shape> myShapeList;
        Shape shape;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void AddShape(Shape myshape)
        {
            myShapeList.Add(shape);
        }

        public List<Shape> MyShapeList
        {
            get { return myShapeList; }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myShapeList = new List<Shape>();
            shape = new Shape();
        }

        private void drawMeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EditShape editShape = new EditShape();
            editShape.Shape = shape;

            if (editShape.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.shape = editShape.Shape;
                myShapeList.Add(shape);
                panel1.Invalidate();
            }
            editShape.Dispose();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int panelWidth = panel1.ClientRectangle.Width;
            int panelHeight = panel1.ClientRectangle.Height;

            Pen penLine = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            if (myShapeList != null)
            {
                foreach (Shape element in myShapeList)
                {
                    label1.Text = element.Width.ToString();
                    g.DrawRectangle(penLine, element.XCordinates, element.XCordinates, 50, 50); 
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

and here is code for my edit shape dialog box

```
namespace DrawShapes
{
    public partial class EditShape : Form
    {
        Shape shape = null;



        public EditShape()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Shape Shape
        {
            get { return shape; }
            set { shape = value; }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            shape.Width = 50;
            shape.Height = 50;
            shape.XCordinates = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            shape.YCordinates = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            shape.Type = 0;
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

        }
    }
}
```

I am having problem assigning shape object(from Edit Shape form) to myShapeList, all properties are set to 0 for some reason. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake.I Created new event handler with wrong parameters. Therefore information that suppose to be passed by my dialog OK button was never correctly assigned. Silly mistake. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is your `AddShape` method. You seem to be adding `shape` each time instead of the shape that's getting passed into the method (`myshape`).

What happens if you do this instead?

```
public void AddShape(Shape myshape)
{
    myShapeList.Add(myshape); // myshapeinstead of shape
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not actually adding your shape to your shapelist. You're taking in myShape and then trying to add in shape. This should come up as an intellisense error.

```
public void AddShape(Shape myshape)
    {
        myShapeList.Add(shape);
    }
```

EDIT: Nevermind, it wouldn't come up as an error because you have a member variable named shape. You're getting zero for everything because it's calling the default constructor for shape.

Comment: Hi Chris I was trying with proper constructor + values from edidShape : shape = new Shape(editShape.Shape.value etc. ) shape properties results are coming as zero value.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is in your call to the edit form. You are adding to the list the same object reference. So when you modify the reference inside the edit form you change all the elements added to the list to the inputs set in the latest call

Change your code to

```
private void drawMeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(EditShape editShape = new EditShape())
    {
        // Here, create a new instance of a Shape and edit it....
        editShape.Shape = new Shape();
        if (editShape.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Add the new instance to the list, not the same instance
            // declared globally. (and, at this point, useless)
            myShapeList.Add(editShape.Shape);
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }
        // The using blocks makes this call superflous
        // editShape.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then it is not clear when you call the method AddShape(Shape myshape) but it is clear that you have typo in that method

Comment: Thx Steve. Unfortunately my property values are still 0. AddShape method is just a residue of my previous attempts to solve this problem.